# Projection from a general point of a variety of degree $d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I've stumbled across the following statement.

> Assume you have a non-degenerate, normal complex projective surface $X
>  \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d$ and $n > 3$. Projection from a general point
>    $p \in X$ induces a birational map $\psi \colon X \dashrightarrow X'
>  \subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. Then the degree of $X'$ is $d-1$.

I'm a little bit confused about this.

Questions:

1) How is $\psi$ defined? Of course, a projection is just $q \mapsto \overline{pq} \cap \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, so my question is: What is the $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ they are speaking about? Is it just the hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^n$ perpendicular to $p$?

2) What is the inverse map? To me it seems like it is not defined in the points of $X'$ which have fibres of cardinality $>1$, which should be the general fibre.

3) Why is the degree of $X'$ equal to $d-1$?

Comment: You are missing some hypothesis in general, unless the second sentence is part of the assumption. Consider the case when $X$ is a hypersurface.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the assumption that $X$ should be a surface and $n > 3$. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: You say, stumbled upon-but where. All these are standard facts and can be read in many standard books. I can explain these, but it may be better that you read them in a book (say Shafarevich).